# Execute manage.py runserver using Upstart in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, django, ubuntu-16.04, upstart

I have a small project using Raspberry Pi 3 device and using Django for my application. I follow this [tutorial](http://www.dangtrinh.com/2013/08/django-using-upstart-to-run-django.html) but sadly it can't be used for 16.04. I'm not using apache because of my device, i want to use runserver because of the limitations of my unit.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error/problem you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `manage.py runserver` for production servers. You should use something like WSGI or Gunicorn: [How To Set Up Django with Postgres, Nginx, and Gunicorn on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: Thanks for this Nils.

Comment: I follow this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04), i'm not using virtualenv. In the ExecStart i use 
`ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn --workers 2 --bind 0.0.0.0.8080 mysite.wsgi:application` but it gets error, /usr/bin/gunicorn: No such file or directory.

Comment: I used virtualenv for this. Thanks again.